# Список объектов класса ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Product

c1 = Product.new
c2 = Product.new
```

Подскажите, как получить именно список имен экземпляров класса?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `c1` и `c2` - не имена экземпляров класса. Это переменные, содержащие ссылку на объект. Следовательно 2 переменные могут содержать ссылку на один и тот же объект.

Answer (score 3):

```
local_variables.select do |variable|
     product = eval(variable.to_s)
     product.instance_of? Product
end
```

Получите массив символов, с именами переменных класса Product.

Answer (score 1):

Пример для получения `Enumerator` со ссылками на экземпляры одной строкой:

Пустой тестовый класс:

```
?> class Test
>> end
=> nil
```

Экземпляры:

```
>> a = Test.new
=> #<Test:0x007fdaf99732f0>
>> b = Test.new
=> #<Test:0x007fdaf995aae8>
```

Собственно выборка:

```
>> ObjectSpace.each_object(Test).to_a
=> [#<Test:0x007fdaf995aae8>, #<Test:0x007fdaf99732f0>]
```